# Javascript removeChild not removing all elements inside loop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

What am I trying to do -

1. Get all the elements of a particular class from DOM through javascript
2. Get `img` element from parent of the element
3. Insert `img` element before the parent
4. Remove the parent element

Here is the code:

```
let elms = el.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
console.log(elms) // 6 elements are printed here
for (let elm of elms) {
    console.log("Inside loop") //only printed 3 times
    let elm_parent = elm.parentNode;
    let img_elm = elm_parent.getElementsByTagName("img");
    elm.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(img_elm[0], elm_parent);
    elm.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(elm_parent);
} 
//Loop only executes 3 times
```

Here is the structure of HTML (there are total 6 such elements):

```
<p>
    <div style="position: relative; display: block;">
        <img src="http://something.com/image1" style="display: block;">
        <div></div><svg class="my-class" viewBox="0 0 341 102">
            <g>
                <g class="a9s-selection" style="pointer-events: none;">
                    <rect class="outer" x="-1.5" y="58" width="147" height="40"></rect>
                    <rect class="inner" x="-1.5" y="58" width="147" height="40"></rect>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <br>
</p>
```

As you can see that although `elms` has 6 elements, the loop is only executed 3 times. Can anyone help me understand why is this happening?

Comment: can you sharer the structure of  your html?

Comment: @AlanOmar Done...

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection of the elements, that messes the iteration. Don't use `.getElementsBy*` anywhere, use `.querySelectorAll` instead.

Comment: @Teemu Using `querySelectorAll` solves the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem: Call by reference of an object.

When you do `el.getElementsByClassName("my-class");` it will give you a live `HTMLCollection` object which looks like an array. Which is handled by DOM itself.
If you remove anything from the DOM which is present in `HTMLCollection` the length of that `HTMLCollection` also decreases.

## Solution: Create a copy of `HTMLCollection` in a form of an array.

```
let elms = el.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
elms = Array.from(elms);
```